# How many Functions Can I add to delegate at a Time

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates

I have a Delegate method in C# where I have to reference more than one function...
Can a delegate point to More than one function at a time?
If yes How many functions can it point at a Time?

Comment: Like almost all of the restrictions in .NET, it is limited only by available memory.  Many, many millions.  Fits Raymond Chen's usual advice: "if you need to know then you are doing it wrong" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a delegate can be assigned to multiple objects at the same time, and when you invoke the delegate, the functions will be invoked in the order they were added.
This is called a [MulticastDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) delegate

```
delegate void myDelegate();

void foo()
{
  Console.WriteLine("hello");
}

void bar()
{
  Console.WriteLine("world");
}

void Main()
{
  myDelegate d = foo;
  d+=bar;
  d();
}
```

Produces

```
hello
world
```

With regards to the maximum number of functions you can reference this way - I couldn't find any hard number, but a simple looped test allowed me to add `foo` and `bar` over 10,000 times (before I got bored and hit "break :) so I would say there's *probably* no real practical limit, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Your code has various problems (which you should fix) and it does not compile. Also I am not sure that the OP was referring to delegate accounting for methods sequentially (but well... let's see on this front what the OP has to say).